# Is it possible to set up a password on local repo?

Tags: git, localhost

I have a repo on local disk, a copy of it is as also located on a network drive (directly mounted on windows), where I can share it with colleagues. I would like to limit the access to the repo with a password. Is that possible, or is there another good alternative to achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your remote git repo is mounted on a drive called `Z:`.

The your remote URL will be something like:
`Z:\git\project.git`

Git only handles versioning and it uses the underlying protocol's security, sometimes it's SSH, HTTPS or in your case it's the Windows file system.

So what you should do is managing windows permissions on the `git` or the `project.git` folder so that only authorized people can access it.